# scp to location on remote that requires sudo gives Permission denied error

Tags: linux

I have a ubuntu server to which I login as admin which can do sudo . On this server  I have created dir /opt/myapp. I had to do sudo mkdir otherwise it would not work. Now from my desktop I want to do:

scp myfile admin@example.com:/opt/myapp

but I get Permission denied. But if I

scp myfile admin@example.com:

works fine and myfile is in /home/admin directory.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: if you ssh to `example.com` as `admin`, can you cp your file to `/opt/myapp` ? <edit> because I would expect you can't, that's the same operation `scp` is trying to do, as `admin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First... maybe this is not a good idea.  It may be that the permissions are set this way to stop people from doing exactly what you are trying to do for some good reason.  That said, you are the captain of your destiny.

Find out who can write to that dir.  Do:

```
ls -ld /opt/myapp
```

and you will get something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 myapp_user myapp_group 55 Sep 10  2016 /opt/myapp
```

Potential Option 1:
switch to the user account that is built for that app. eg:

```
scp myfile myapp_user@example.com:/opt/myapp
```

But you likely do not have the password for that user.  Potentially, you can solve that by authenticating with a key.  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-secure-copy-with-ssh-key-authentication/

Potential Option 2:
Change the permissions of the dir '/opt/myapp' to 774 (or 770)

```
chmod 774 /opt/myapp
```

Then make the admin user a member of the group that now has write permissions.  https://www.howtogeek.com/50787/add-a-user-to-a-group-or-second-group-on-linux/  This one is not great as you may run into trouble with being blocked from over-writing files (depending on what is going on).

Comment: ls -ld /opt/myapp gives root root     (user root and group is root)

Comment: So, if I take this information on face value, then you need to connect as root rather than admin.  I use Centos rather than ubuntu, so it may be that ubuntu is doing something interesting with rights of the admin account.  Still, connect as root... that that machine will let you.  (I purposely configure my boxes to disallow this for security reasons.)

Comment: I might point out an Option 3:
This one is complicated, and requires created a Rube Goldberg machine.  
a.  Create a subdir in the home dir for admin.  Something like:  '/home/admin/myapp_inbox'  
b.  Create a script that will check for files in the dir from step 'a'.  If a file is found, move it with sudo to the target dir '/opt/myapp'

Comment: The exact text of this script is too complex to be included here.  
c.  Put the script from step 'b' in a safe location.  I might suggest creating a dir for this such as '/home/admin/bin'.
d.  Add a cron job to run the script as some regular time.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Answer (score 1):

Either do this is two steps:

1. Copy the file to your own homedir on the server
2. Login to the server and move the file using `sudo`

Or if you can do anything with `sudo` without entering a password, you can be creative with `cat`, `tee` and redirections:

`cat myfile | ssh admin@example.com 'sudo tee /opt/myapp/myfile > /dev/null'`

note that you will have to specify the file name twice. *This is not recommended though, there are many things that can fail and cause unwanted results.*